# ASP.NET HttpContext is null in 4.6.1 sample project

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, async-await, asp.net-identity

1) Create new MVC app targeting 4.6.1 (not core, using MSVS 2015 Update 3)

2) In the generated class ApplicationUser.cs add an assertion:

```
public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
{
     HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
     Debug.Assert(httpContext != null);  // assertion fails
     // ...
}
```

3) Run program in the debugger, login, the assertion fires.

[This workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38339065/538763) fixes the problem however I was told that HttpContext should be available across async/await as of .NET 4.5.  Should I need the workaround?

Web.Config:

```
 <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28427675/correct-way-to-use-httpcontext-current-user-with-async-await (this might be helpful)

Comment: How does this function get called? From a controller?

Comment: Looks like the sample project calls it from two places:  1) ApplicationSignInManager, 2) Startup.Auth.cs  Cookie setup, OnValidateIdentity event handled by SecurityStampValidator regenerateIdentity (really should see the code).

Comment: interesting.. context is null only at Login. But when you register, proper context available in same method

Comment: It probably has more to do with the code path leading to this method than anything else. Note in the link that Sami provided that if a method uses `.ConfigureAwait(false)` and then calls into this code (directly or indirectly), then HttpContext is going to be null.